Error obj is not defined with pyinstaller when crating an EXE
I've created a script that calculates the p-value using the Sum Rank method, when I run the scripts it's all ok, but when I run the .exe from command prompt, I get the following error:
D:\Scipts_homemade\dist>P_value_SUM_TEST.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P_value_SUM_TEST.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 608, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "scipy\stats\_stats_py.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "scipy\stats\distributions.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 360, in <module>
NameError: name 'obj' is not defined
[16680] Failed to execute script 'P_value_SUM_TEST' due to unhandled exception!

In my script, I imported the following libraries:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import ranksums
from openpyxl import load_workbook
def calculate_p_value(data1, data2):
    # Calcola il p-value utilizzando il test di Wilcoxon Rank-Sum
    statistic, p_value = ranksums(data1, data2)
    return p_value

def browse_files():
    # Apre una finestra di dialogo per selezionare il file Excel
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Seleziona un file",
                                          filetypes=((r"Excel files", r"*.xlsx;*.xls"), ("tutti i file", "*.*")))
    entry_file_path.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_file_path.insert(0, filename)

def select_cells():
    # Apre il file Excel e permette all'utente di selezionare manualmente le celle
    file_path = entry_file_path.get()
    try:
        wb = load_workbook(file_path)
        sheet_names = wb.sheetnames

        selection_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
        selection_window.title("Seleziona le celle e il foglio di lavoro")

        label_sheet = tk.Label(selection_window, text="Seleziona il foglio di lavoro:")
        label_sheet.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

        selected_sheet = tk.StringVar()
        selected_sheet.set(sheet_names[0])
        option_menu_sheet = tk.OptionMenu(selection_window, selected_sheet, *sheet_names)
        option_menu_sheet.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

        label_instruction = tk.Label(selection_window, text="Seleziona le celle per le due popolazioni")
        label_instruction.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

        entry_cell_range1 = tk.Entry(selection_window, width=20)
        entry_cell_range1.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
        label_pop1 = tk.Label(selection_window, text="Popolazione 1:")
        label_pop1.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

        entry_cell_range2 = tk.Entry(selection_window, width=20)
        entry_cell_range2.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
        label_pop2 = tk.Label(selection_window, text="Popolazione 2:")
        label_pop2.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

        button_done = tk.Button(selection_window, text="Fatto",
                                command=lambda: get_selected_cells(entry_cell_range1.get(), entry_cell_range2.get(), selected_sheet.get()))
        button_done.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

        def get_selected_cells(range1, range2, selected_sheet):
            # Legge i dati dalle celle selezionate e chiude la finestra di selezione
            ws = wb[selected_sheet]
            data1 = [cell.value for row in ws[range1] for cell in row]
            data2 = [cell.value for row in ws[range2] for cell in row]
            p_value = calculate_p_value(data1, data2)
            label_result.config(text=f"P-value: {p_value}")
            selection_window.destroy()

    except Exception as e:
        label_result.config(text="Errore durante il caricamento del file")

def calculate_and_save():
    # Legge i dati dai file Excel e calcola il p-value
    file_path = entry_file_path.get()
    selected_sheet = tk.StringVar()
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=selected_sheet.get())
        data1 = df.iloc[:, 0].values
        data2 = df.iloc[:, 1].values
        p_value = calculate_p_value(data1, data2)

I have no idea why I get this error. Thanks for all
Is there some bug? Please help me

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
